# How to match two images when draw line between them

Tags: android, android-canvas

Hi every one ..
             in my application I have succeeded draw line between two images code give below 
but i want to match two images between two column when images matched i want to show a toast message.Just like column  1 have a rose images its match to  column 2 by drawing line  after that if both column have same images show toast message.
[image]

```
in MainActivity code :
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(new DrawView(this));
```

================================================
    in DrawView Class:

```
    public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Line l : lines) {
        canvas.drawLine(l.startX, l.startY, l.stopX, l.stopY, paint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        lines.add(new Line(event.getX(), event.getY()));
        return true;
    } else if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || event
            .getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) && lines.size() > 0) {
        Line current = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
        current.stopX = event.getX();
        current.stopY = event.getY();
        invalidate();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

=============================in Line Class:

```
    public class Line {
float startX, startY, stopX, stopY;

public Line(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY) {
    this.startX = startX;
    this.startY = startY;
    this.stopX = stopX;
    this.stopY = stopY;
}

public Line(float startX, float startY) { // for convenience
    this(startX, startY, startX, startY);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Inside your method **onTouchEvent** in **Action_UP** Check the co-ordinates of second end of line and see if they match with the selected image. If they matched or come in between range of image then show a toast message there.